# advanced string management and completion C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Alright, so I'm going to jump in with my situation:

So I have `string[] MyStringArray` with "hello", "goodbye", "morning" in it,
And now I have a normal string `MatchString = "hel"`,
Now, on a specific trigger, I'd like to be able to loop through the strings in `MyStringArray`, and find the most likely match, and replace.
So for instance, say I had the string "Hello, and good mor" and then I trigger the event, I'd want the resulting string to be "Hello, and good morning".
Same would be true for "I have got to go, go" -> "I have got to go, goodbye"

EDIT: I want on the trigger to only take the last word, separated by a space.

Comment: and the MyStringArray is always changing...

Comment: i was playing with splitting the last word up into char[] arrays to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

errrr....

why doesn't "i have got to go, go"  turn into "i have got to goodbye, gooodbye"?

and..

"Hello, and good mor"   isn't   "Hello, and goodbye morning"

Comment: read  my edits... i stated id only be taking the last word of the string

Comment: ahhh, the edit helps....   match from the end finding characters,  then use startswith and your string array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .StartsWith() method, i.e.

```
foreach (var str in MatchArray)
{
    if (str.StartsWith(MatchString))
    {
        //it's a possible match
    }
}
```

But you have to deal with multiple matches seperately

Answer (score 0):

[Intellisense: Home-Made - Based on Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/JGIntelli.aspx) By James Gupta